# Minimum energy configuration of N charged particles in a circular enclosure

Tags: optimization

I came across this paper which describes minimum energy configuration for N **equal** point charges in a circular enclosure which seem to form shell like structure. For lower values of N local optimum is point charges spaced equidistant from each other on the circumference. As N increases one out of N is pushed inwards and shell began to form.

I was wondering what would happen if we introduce one more electron of charge 2e in the system i.e. (N-1) charges will have charge +e while one has charge +2e. What would be minimum energy configuration in such scenario (for lower values of N say) or possible local optimum(at least)? Will charges be equidistant from each other (I don't think so)?

**Edit:**

One local optimum that I am aware of is inserting a +2e charge in the center. However, placing all N charges around the perimeter results in a lower equilibrium energy (I have computationally confirmed this for N up to 4).

I am looking for optimum configuration when all N charges are placed on the circumference.

[image: Minimum energy configuration for different values of M]

Comment: I would expect that the "special" charge will be put in the center in order to preserve rotational symmetry, and I think someone more knowledgeable about this area could prove so rather easily.

Comment: Putting the "special" charge at center is one of the possibility and it is one of local optimum. But I was wondering what sort of geometry arises when it is instead on the circumference. What will be local optimum in such scenario?

Comment: Hmm, okay. If you want to only consider the case with the special charge on the circumference, you might want to make it clearer in the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$, let $q_i$ be the charge of point $i$, with $q_1=2$ and $q_i=1$ for $i\not= 1$.
Let decision variables $(x_i,y_i)$ represent the coordinates of point $i$.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{i<j} \frac{q_i q_j}{\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+(y_i-y_j)^2}}$$
subject to
$x_i^2 + y_i^2 \le 1$ for all $i$.
Without loss of optimality, you can optionally fix $y_1=0$ and impose $x_1 \ge 0$.

Up to $N=10$, it looks like it is optimal to have all charges on the circumference but not equidistant:
[image]

\begin{matrix}
     i &q_i &x_i        &y_i       &\theta_i   &\theta_i - \theta_{i-1} \\ 
\hline
     1 &2 &1        &0        &0 \\ 
     2 &1 &0.71322  &0.70094  &0.77672 &0.77672 \\
     3 &1 &0.19341  &0.98112  &1.37616 &0.59944 \\
     4 &1 &-0.38571 &0.92262  &1.96677 &0.59061 \\
     5 &1 &-0.83264 &0.55381  &2.55465 &0.58788 \\
     6 &1 &-1       &0        &3.14159 &0.58694 \\
     7 &1 &-0.83264 &-0.55381 &3.72853 &0.58694 \\
     8 &1 &-0.38571 &-0.92262 &4.31642 &0.58788 \\
     9 &1 &0.19341  &-0.98112 &4.90703 &0.59061 \\
    10 &1 &0.71322  &-0.70094 &5.50647 &0.59944 \\
\end{matrix}
For $N=11$, it is better to have a 1e charge in the interior but not exactly at the center:
[image]

Comment: May I know how exactly did you arrive at the configuration for N=10?

Comment: I used the NLP solver (with the multistart option) in SAS.

Comment: Thanks a lot RobPratt!

Comment: @RobPratt Because some symmetry prevails in the diagram for the case $n=10$, I thought the angular distance (or the distance) between any two neighbouring unit (+1) charged particles is the same. In order to convince myself, I measured the mentioned angles. But, I found that they are not even approximately equal. Can you please give me the $x-$ and $y-$ coordinates of the 4 unit-charged particles on the top half of the circle, if you have them?

Comment: @YNK I added the coordinates to my answer.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you very much!